# Get related rows from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I have just one SQL query that I want help for.

As you can see below, there are 4 emails. 3 of the 4 messages are related (15482, 15483 and 15484). I would like to have these rows out.

You can relate them to each other through column messageid = ReplyTo and ReplyTo = MessageID. It ends up being recrusiv.

The picture below shows what I have right now, but as I said I only want the ID 15482, 15483 and 15484 shown and not 15485.  Because as you can see, the first 3 rows is an email thread that hangs together while the last is a new mail

How can I do that, when I only know ID 15482

This is my SQL statement

```
select 
    t1.id, t1.From_, t1.MessageId, t2.ReplyTo 
from 
    HelpDesk_Z01_Emails as t1 
left join 
    HelpDesk_Z01_EmailsReplyTo as t2 on t1.MessageId = t2.MessageId
```

This is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly said that it is a recursion.
Usually it is done using [recursive common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

I'm not sure if everything in the query below is correct. If you had provided a simplified example with sample data it would be possible to try the suggested solution. Without it, the query is written, but not tested. Give it a try.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        t1.id, t1.From_, t1.MessageId, t2.ReplyTo
    FROM
        HelpDesk_Z01_Emails as t1
        left join HelpDesk_Z01_EmailsReplyTo as t2 on t1.MessageId = t2.MessageId
    WHERE t1.id = 15482

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        t1.id, t1.From_, t1.MessageId, t2.ReplyTo
    FROM
        HelpDesk_Z01_Emails as t1
        left join HelpDesk_Z01_EmailsReplyTo as t2 on t1.MessageId = t2.MessageId
        INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.MessageId = t2.ReplyTo
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
;
```

This is the script to make a simplified table with sample data that you should have included in your question:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(id int, From_ varchar(255), MessageId varchar(255), ReplyTo varchar(255));

INSERT INTO @T (id, From_, MessageId, ReplyTo) VALUES (15482, 'test@com', 'CAF', NULL);
INSERT INTO @T (id, From_, MessageId, ReplyTo) VALUES (15483, 'test@com', '54c', 'CAF');
INSERT INTO @T (id, From_, MessageId, ReplyTo) VALUES (15484, 'test@com', 'Fk', '54c');
INSERT INTO @T (id, From_, MessageId, ReplyTo) VALUES (15485, 'test@com', 'FkMh', NULL);
```

Having such starting point it is easy to write and **verify** the following query:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        TT.id, TT.From_, TT.MessageId, TT.ReplyTo
    FROM
        @T AS TT
    WHERE TT.id = 15482

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        TT.id, TT.From_, TT.MessageId, TT.ReplyTo
    FROM
        @T AS TT
        INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.MessageId = TT.ReplyTo
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
;
```

The result set:

```
id       From_       MessageId    ReplyTo
15482    test@com    CAF          NULL
15483    test@com    54c          CAF
15484    test@com    Fk           54c
```